# Swift iOS - How can I analyze a given MP3 file to determine what time the beats are at?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer, core-audio

I want to make an app that will find what timestamps the beats are at, as well as the "long notes", and generally I want to know everything about the track and store it in an array of "properties" which would look like this, let's say (for the beats):

`beatsTimeStamps = [1, 4, 7, 10, 12]` (all integers are in seconds). i.e. These would be the times at which a beat occurs in a 15 second track, let's say.

Another example would be a dictionary that stores info about long chords, such as:

`longChordsTimeIntervals: [1: 4, 7:10, 15:20]`, which follows the format `[beginningTimeStampOfChord1: endingTimeStampOfChord1, beginningTimeStampOfChord2: endingTimeStampOfChord2, etc....].`

It would also be preferable to know what notes the chord consists of, but that's probably way harder.

How can I go about analyzing an audio track to get this sort of information ? None of the 3rd-party iOS Audio frameworks out there seem to do this easily.

Comment: This sounds like an advanced task. You need matlab and lots of knowledge on DSP to do this, then recode the template in obj-c using Accelerate framework to make it fast. I do not know any libraries that can do what you want.

Comment: Is Matlab an absolute must or can the audio processing be done on iOS ? What kind of audio processing would be required ? What do you mean exactly by "recode the template" (I use Swift by the way, I'm more into modern technologies). What template would I be recoding ? Can you elaborate on everything that would need to happen to accomplish this ? Thanks

Comment: Matlab is used to easily experiment (it has convenient syntax and easy visualization tools).  Once you find proper solution in matlab you can rewrite it to Swift (this is what i mean by "recode the template"). You can skip the matlab part, but that makes things even more difficult. I'd say that doing this is like a few weeks of work for a DSP expert, whom unfortunately I am not.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a DSP expert either LOL. I understand what you mean now. Do you think all this audio processing would require an incredibly fast processor or would it be feasible a 64-bit A9 processor or A8 processor ? Do you have any idea at all on the kind of libraries I could use on Matlab to get a good idea of how to process this audio ?

Comment: Audio processing can be easily done on an iPhone, there's apple library (part of Accelerate: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/index.html) that specifically deals with DSP performance. I wouldn't touch it without good C knowledge, though. Try some libs hotpaw2 mentioned, they might abstract that out for you. I am no matlab expert so cannot recommend anything concrete. I just know from some professionals I worked with that this is the way to go.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

There are tons of research papers on state-of-the-art in the areas of Audio Tempo Estimation and Audio Beat Tracking on the MIREX music-ir web site.

http://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/MIREX_HOME

http://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/2015:Audio_Tempo_Estimation

http://www.music-ir.org/mirex/wiki/2015:Audio_Beat_Tracking

It's not something to be simply found in the standard iOS Audio Frameworks.  iOS devices likely have more than enough compute power, but creating the algorithm and the code will not be trivial.

There's also stuff on the MIREX site on polyphonic pitch estimation, but that is much harder than beat tracking.

Comment: Happy to know that iOS devices have the power required to analyze audio files (after Terminus' comments, I was actually worried that this was going to require a quad-core i7!). Thank you for your insight.

Comment: you could try [aubio](https://aubio.org), which includes beat and note detection, and runs on iOS.